# Filtration data by category in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

### Index Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $blogs = Blog::all();
        $categories = Category:all();

        return view('blog', compact('blogs', 'categories'));
    }
```

We have something like the following code on the blog page. First we get all the **available categories**, then a **list of all blogs**.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="category-filter" id="filter">
     <div class="category-filter_item active">All</div>
     @foreach($categories as $category)
     <div class="category-filter_item">{{ $category->title }}</div>
     @endforeach
</div>

@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <div class="blog-list {{ $blog->category_id}}">
        <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Can you please help to suggest a filtering function that, when choosing a specific category, will pull up all blogs from this category by ID?

### JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.category-filter_item').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document
      .querySelector('.category-filter_item.active')
      .classList.remove('active');
    el.classList.add('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax in your case by sending an ajax request to your backend and you handle the data, then you return a response, this an example of a function in controller.

```
public function ajaxResponse(Request $request){
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $cat_id = $request->input('cat');

            $blogs = Blog::query();
            if ($cat_id != null) {
                $blogs->whereHas("categories", function ($query) use ($cat_id) {
                    $query->whereIn('category_id', explode(',', $cat_id));
                })->get();
            }

            $blogs = $blogs->get();

            $blog = view('articles.ajaxblogs', ['blogs' => $blogs])->render();
        }
        return response()->json(['blog' => $blog]);
    }
```

Make sure to include category id in request.